# How to order divs with CSS flex and use Jquery Sortable function as well

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I want to order div's.
I used CSS flex properties and ordered the div's, but when I do this, the jQuery UI sort is not working.

Is any other way to order div's with only CSS/HTML? I don't want to use any JavaScript to achieve this.
Please see the code below.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#main").sortable();
      $("#main").disableSelection();
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    #main {
      /*width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;*/
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
    }
    #main div {
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
    }
    /* Standard syntax */
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="main">
    <div style="background-color:coral;" id="myRedDIV" runat="server" order="1"></div>
    <div style="background-color:lightblue;" id="myBlueDIV" runat="server" order="3"></div>
    <div style="background-color:lightgreen;" id="myGreenDIV" runat="server" order="2"></div>
    <div style="background-color:pink;" id="myPinkDIV" runat="server" order="4"></div>
  </div>

</html>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //foreach(var i in div)
    //{
        //i.Attributes.CssStyle["order"] = "1";
    //}
    myRedDIV.Attributes.CssStyle["order"] = "1";
    myPinkDIV.Attributes.CssStyle["order"] = "2";
    myBlueDIV.Attributes.CssStyle["order"] = "3";
    myGreenDIV.Attributes.CssStyle["order"] = "4";  
}
```

Now when I change the order in .cs page, the sort function is not working.

Comment: You code snippet seems to work for me. I can re-order then fine.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, making it sortable when the page loads (and the user can drag the order), or having the correct order already in place when page load? As far as I can see both are working fine. By calling `sortable()` you have made that div drag and sortable. Secondly, you cannot have a sortable flexboxes like that without javascript.